# Small UITableView, remove dequeReuseableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, deque

I've read around so don't knock this as a duplicate unless my searching has been completely awful.

Basically I have a small table (5 Fixed rows) however they do have indexes associated with them in a tuple (this is why I'm using the dynamic way rather than a static way.

The players goal is to swap the cells around. I am not using a nib to get these cells populated, this is how.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellID = "Cell"
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! DefinitionMatchTableViewCell

    customCell.background.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(2.0)

    if tableView == nameTableLeft{
        customCell.textToDislay!.text = nameList[indexPath.row].0
        customCell.background.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 192/255, blue: 1/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let cellIDFromTuple = nameList[indexPath.row].1
       customCell.tag = cellIDFromTuple
    }

    if tableView == definitionTableRight{
        customCell.textToDislay!.text = definitionList[indexPath.row].0
        customCell.background.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
        let cellIDFromTupleForDefinition = definitionList[indexPath.row].1
        customCell.tag = cellIDFromTupleForDefinition
    }

    customCell.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    customCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return customCell
}
```

Now the problem is that on an iPhone SE the 5 cells can't fit which results in the top or bottom cell losing it's reference ID when checking if the values match. This makes the game impossible to complete, I need a way so I can populate the table with an index value associated with each string but so the table doesn't reuse the cell but it remains in memory.

The only method I can think of is writing a static table with the data but then providing each cell with an invisible index that it carries associated with the string. However I'd much rather do it dynamically.

Any advice on to keep the state of these cells would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Here is the way I check the answers based on my index values in the table. I imagine the problem comes from .indexPathsForVisibleRows as some aren't visible

```
    for index in nameTableLeft.indexPathsForVisibleRows!{
            let leftCell = nameTableLeft.cellForRow(at: index) as? DefinitionMatchTableViewCell
            let rightCell = definitionTableRight.cellForRow(at: index) as? DefinitionMatchTableViewCell

if nameTableLeft.cellForRow(at: index)?.tag == definitionTableRight.cellForRow(at: index)?.tag{
                leftCell?.background.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                rightCell?.background.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                counter += 1
            }else{
                leftCell?.background.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                rightCell?.background.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            }
        }
```

As you can see I then check the values match up on the tags. However I'm struggling with this concept if I used something Different.

**My Model**

```
var nameList : [(String, Int)] = [("Trojan", 0),
                                  ("Virus", 1),
                                  ("Spyware", 2),
                                  ("Ransomware", 3),
                                  ("Leakware", 4)]
var definitionList : [(String, Int)] = [("Attaches onto another program. Replicates itself. Something loaded onto your device without your knowledge. Continues to spread", 0),
                                        ("When malware is disguised as something else. Usually an e-mail attachment", 1),
                                        ("Tracks a user's actions, this includes login details, internet habits and any secure accounts", 2),
                                        ("Locks a device or encrypts files and demands money to unlock it", 3),
                                        ("Threatens to distribute your information", 4)]
```

**Edit 2**

Thanks to some help in the answers I had decided to add this to my answer checking.

```
 for answerIndex in 0...4{
            if definitionList[answerIndex].1 == nameList[answerIndex].1{
                print("MATCH")
                counter += 1
            }else{
                print("NO MATCH")
            }
        }
```

I jumble both the definition and name lists to start with. I then decide to look at both of the indexes placed in the tuple based on the tables total length. Unfortunately I had to resort to magic numbers are you cannot iterate through a tuple.

So this little loop decides if the indexes line up in my tuples and if they do it's correct otherwise it's not. Thanks again everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also solved a similar problem. My advise is to keep reusing the cells. Store the data corresponding to each cell externally in a separate model class. Then store it in a mutable array. When you shuffle the cells, shuffle the data in the mutable array.

It can be done in the following way.

The `model` class

```
class model: NSObject {

   var name: String = ""
   var definition: String = ""
   var type: String = ""

   required init(name: String, definition: String, type: String) {
       super.init()

       self.name = name
       self.definition = definition
       self.type = type
   }
}
```

Custom `UITableViewCell` - trivial example for different layouts

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var nameLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var definitionLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)      
    {
       super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

       nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
       nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
       nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
       self.contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)

       definitionLabel.textColor = UIColor.brown
       definitionLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
       definitionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
       self.contentView.addSubview(definitionLabel)
    } 

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()

       nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width:   self.contentView.frame.size.width - 20, height: self.contentView.frame.size.height - 20)
       definitionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.contentView.frame.size.width - 20, height: self.contentView.frame.size.height - 20)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

Registering the cell:

```
self.tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Using the `CustomTableViewCell` according to model:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    if model.type == "name" {
        cell.nameLabel.text = model.name
        cell.definitionLabel.isHidden = true
    }else if model.type == "definition" {
        cell.definitionLabel.text = model.definition
        cell.nameLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

The moving cells part:

```
let mutableArray:[model] = [model1, model2, model3, model4, model5] // model class holds data for each cell

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
     let source = sourceIndexPath.row;
     let destination = destinationIndexPath.row;

     let sourceModel = mutableArray[source]
     let destinationModel = mutableArray[destination]

     mutableArray[source] = destinationModel
     mutableArray[destination] = sourceModel
}
```

Feel free to comment if you have any doubts regarding this implementation. Feel free to suggest edits to make this better :)

**Edit:-**

Even if it's a tuple with it's index position, you can change the values when the rows moved accordingly.

```
var nameList : [(String, Int)] = [("Trojan", 0),
                                  ("Virus", 1),
                                  ("Spyware", 2),
                                  ("Ransomware", 3),
                                  ("Leakware", 4)]

let source = sourceIndexPath.row
let destination = destinationIndexPath.row

var sourceTuple: (String, Int) = nameList[source]
var destinationTuple: (String, Int) = nameList[destination]

sourceTuple.1 = destination
destinationTuple.1 = source

nameList[destination] = sourceTuple
nameList[source] = destinationTuple
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I was looking at this. So source and destination are just static for you or is that an example? I see that you're basically swapping the data this way. How did you do your cells then? Static based? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I am sorry. I edited the answer. `source` and `destination` corresponds to `sourceIndexPath.row` and `destinationIndexPath.row`. The cells are Prototype Cells created programatically. If we need a cells with different layout that can also be done. Because the model holds all the data for any particular cell. Shall I add an example for CustomCell and `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: If you'd be so kind that would be great. I know I shouldn't really fight the system of the UITableView but it just seems logical to me. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @CardDeath, edited the answer with relevant content as discussed. Let me know if you have any doubts in this

Comment: Ok this look pretty cool Krishna, thanks again. Just a question though. In my project I need to compare the values from model to the other but these positions can be in difference positions in the list. This is why I was originally using a tuple. Each object has a Int as an index that I then compared with my edit above (please see the end of the question) I am cycling through checking them based on the index path and the index number contained within.

Comment: @CardDeath, Even if it's a tuple, you can change it's values accordingly to match your need. Please check my edited answer for details.

Comment: Hey man thanks. I didn't exactly do what you said but it inspired me to try something and it works. I had to do some fiddling with the appearance but the data was fine. I will do a 2nd update so you can see :) Thank you for your patience, I've marked your answer! :)))

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should expect cells to be reused and not store state in your cells.  But if you want a quick answer then set a different reuse identifier for every cell.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I create 5 prototype cells that are the same with different reuse identifiers? How would I then make a call inside of the code?  Thanks for your time

Comment: I thought you said you were not using a nib. You can register a class for your reuse identifier like     [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell1"];, and the same for cell2 etc.

Comment: You're correct I'm not using a nib. Thanks Jon I'll give that a try and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Ok so I've been playing around with this. So If I register the cell class 5 times for the cell types. Could you please explain how I then populate the data? I've just been googling about it but I can't seem to find an answer? I need to get a hold of a cell so I can populate it but I'm not sure how. Thanks again

Comment: i'll repeat again that this is a BAD solution.  It is a quick and easy fix that _may_ work for _most_ of the time.  If you are making a quick prototype then _maybe_ this is an Ok solution. But if you release this code in any real way then you should really do it right and not store state in your cell.  The answer above is correct and my answer is wrong.

Comment: Jon, I completely understand. All I knew this table was a small table (5 cells) and that it was just used as a holder to swap data around in a matching game. Of course if I was using a large model I would of course reuse the data. Your suggestion is good it's just that for this I know it's safe, it's simply because the Iphone SE was too small to host all 5 cells on the screen at once. As I said my solution is a sort of work around that will work for this. Thanks for all your help.